# Pip list shows only one version of `torch`, yet conda list shows two

Tags: pip, anaconda, conda, pytorch

[pip list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk5G5.png)

[conda list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaSvM.png)

I once install `torch 0.1.12`, then I remove it, and reinstall it.
How can I remove the 0.1.12 version?

Comment: try 'conda remove --name package_name'

Comment: conda clean --packages

Answer (score 0):

If you install `torch 0.1.12` with

`conda install pytorch torchvision cuda80 -c soumith`,

then just try

`conda uninstall pytorch torchvision cuda80 -c soumith`.

I tested on my mac and it successfully removed pytorch and all its dependencies, also `pytorch 0.1.12` never shows in `conda list` later.

P.S.: a virtual environment is highly recommended with anaconda.